# How to avoid making multiple SSL negotiations when using IIS

Tags: browser, ssl, iis-7, httpresponse

I am using IIS7 and all our files are served through HTTPS. While looking at the Waterfall View (WebPageTest), I noticed that it takes a some time to do the SSL negotiations for each file. Is there a way I can configure the server or increase timeout for the SSL or TCP connection in IIS 7.0 or Windows so that the browser uses the initial SSL negotiation to make subsequent requests for all the files on that page or during a user's session?

I would appreciate your help.
[image]

Comment: IIS and browsers do this normally. This feature is called SSL session resumption.

Answer (score 4):

SSL is being re-negotiated because the connections are being dropped.  You need to enable keep-alive on IIS (no idea why it's not on by default).  Looks like this shows you how to do it on IIS 7: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpProtocol

Comment: To clarify, in IIS 7 ... httpProtocol  - The default value is true.[See](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpprotocol)